# MassTransit: When using UseDelayedExchangeMessageScheduler messages sent with ScheduleSend ends up in the skipped queue

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm trying to send a Scheduled Message using the `UseDelayedExchangeMessageScheduler` along with the `rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange` plugin. I do setup the bus like this:

```
    public void StartUpBus()
    {
        _bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(ConfigureBus);
        _bus.Start();
    }

    private void ConfigureBus(IRabbitMqBusFactoryConfigurator busConfigurator)
    {
        var host = busConfigurator.Host(new Uri(_connectionInfo.ConnectionString), h =>
            {
                h.Username(_connectionInfo.User);
                h.Password(_connectionInfo.Password);
            });

        busConfigurator.UseDelayedExchangeMessageScheduler();

        busConfigurator.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "schedule-send-endpoint.inbox", endpoint => {

            endpoint.PrefetchCount = 1;

            endpoint.Consumer( () => new AScheduledConsumer() );
        });

    }
```

The consumer is simple as this

```
public class AScheduledConsumer : IConsumer<AScheduledMessage>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<AScheduledMessage> context)
    {
        return Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Message received at {DateTime.Now}");
    }
}
```

Here is the message I'd like to send

```
// Simple role interface to easily identify bus travelling data
public interface IMessage 
{
}

public class AScheduledMessage : IMessage
{
}
```

Then I try to send the message with something like this

```
        var message = new AScheduledMessage();
        var delay = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        Uri destinationUri = new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/schedule-send-endpoint.inbox");
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Message sent at {DateTime.Now}");
        return _bus.ScheduleSend(
            destinationUri,
            delay,
            message
        );
```

I expected to have the message delivered about one minute after the send, but the message ends in the _skipped queue. Here after the message as it is dumped by the "Get Message" function in the RabbitMq management ui.

```
The server reported 0 messages remaining.

Exchange        schedule-send-endpoint.inbox_skipped
Routing Key 
Redelivered     ○
Properties  
message_id:     d7040000-4392-98e7-c8e1-08d7e3d61e54
correlation_id: d7040000-4392-98e7-cc70-08d7e3d61e49
delivery_mode:  2
headers:    
Content-Type:       application/vnd.masstransit+json
MT-Host-Assembly:   Infrastructure.Messaging.RabbitMq.Test.ConsoleApp
MT-Host-AssemblyVersion:    1.0.0.0
MT-Host-FrameworkVersion:   4.0.30319.42000
MT-Host-MachineName:        GABROS-NB
MT-Host-MassTransitVersion: 5.2.1.1808
MT-Host-OperatingSystemVersion: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
MT-Host-ProcessId:      26984
MT-Host-ProcessName:    Infrastructure.Messaging.RabbitMq.Test.ConsoleApp.vshost
MT-Reason:              dead-letter
infrastructure.correlation-id:  029ea5c6-e5ee-44b7-8851-84d3b6ebd191
infrastructure.user-id: anonymous
publishId:  1
content_type:   application/vnd.masstransit+json
Payload
1649 bytes
Encoding: string
{
  "messageId": "d7040000-4392-98e7-c8e1-08d7e3d61e54",
  "correlationId": "d7040000-4392-98e7-cc70-08d7e3d61e49",
  "conversationId": "d7040000-4392-98e7-29ed-08d7e3d61e5d",
  "sourceAddress": "rabbitmq://localhost/bus-GABROS-NB-Infrastructure.Messaging.RabbitMq.Test.ConsoleApp.vshost-4hnyyynd1kcqqhmibdm68io7fu?durable=false&autodelete=true",
  "destinationAddress": "rabbitmq://localhost/schedule-send-endpoint.inbox",
  "messageType": [
    "urn:message:MassTransit.Scheduling:ScheduleMessage[[Infrastructure.Messaging.Test:AScheduledMessage]]",
    "urn:message:MassTransit.Scheduling:ScheduleMessage"
  ],
  "message": {
    "correlationId": "d7040000-4392-98e7-cc70-08d7e3d61e49",
    "scheduledTime": "2020-04-18T20:21:47.1796308Z",
    "payloadType": [
      "urn:message:Infrastructure.Messaging.Test:AScheduledMessage",
      "urn:message:Infrastructure.Messaging:IMessage"
    ],
    "destination": "rabbitmq://localhost/schedule-send-endpoint.inbox",
    "payload": {}
  },
  "sentTime": "2020-04-18T20:21:46.8178828Z",
  "headers": { },
  "host": {
    "machineName": "GABROS-NB",
    "processName": "Infrastructure.Messaging.RabbitMq.Test.ConsoleApp.vshost",
    "processId": 26984,
    "assembly": "Infrastructure.Messaging.RabbitMq.Test.ConsoleApp",
    "assemblyVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "frameworkVersion": "4.0.30319.42000",
    "massTransitVersion": "5.2.1.1808",
    "operatingSystemVersion": "Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0"
  }
}
```

And these are the Exchanges I find in the RabbitMQ

```
Name                                                                                                Type    Features    Message rate in Message rate out+/-
(AMQP default)                                                                                      direct  D       
Infrastructure.Messaging.Test:AScheduledMessage                                                     fanout  D       
amq.direct                                                                                          direct  D       
amq.fanout                                                                                          fanout  D       
amq.headers                                                                                         headers D       
amq.match                                                                                           headers D       
amq.rabbitmq.trace                                                                                  topic   D I     
amq.topic                                                                                           topic   D       
bus-GABROS-NB-Infrastructure.Messaging.RabbitMq.Test.ConsoleApp.vshost-4hnyyynd1kcqqysnbdm6jy77ny   fanout  AD      
schedule-send-endpoint.inbox                                                                        fanout  D           0.00/s          0.00/s
schedule-send-endpoint.inbox_skipped                                                                fanout  D           0.00/s          0.00/s
```

What I find strange is the total absence of an x-delay header in the message and no x-delayed-message Exchange created in rabbitMq, as if the `UseDelayedExchangeMessageScheduler` was totally ignored ... I think I'm doing something wrong, but really can't find the culprit !

**--- UPDATE ---**

As pointed out by @ChrisPatterson, the message must be sent from a `MessageScheduler`.

While still didn't find a solution for MassTransit 5.2.1, this code works using MassTransit v6.4.2 and dotnet core 2:

```cs
var message = new AScheduledMessage();
var delay = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
Uri destinationUri = new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/schedule-send-endpoint.inbox");

var ms = new MessageScheduler(new DelayedExchangeScheduleMessageProvider(bus, bus.Topology as IRabbitMqHostTopology))

await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Message sent at {DateTime.Now}");
return ms.ScheduleSend(
    destinationUri,
    delay,
    message
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are scheduling messages from the bus, and not inside a consumer, you need to use a message scheduler class. What you see happening in your example above is that it is sending to the destinationAddress as if that was Quartz, but it isn't. To use the delayed exchange outside of a `ConsumeContext` you have to create a MessageScheduler class, and pass it the RabbitMQ Delayed Exchange Scheduler Provider.

It isn't obvious, I will update the documentation and try to make it easier for scheduling from the bus using non-Quartz schedulers.

I've also added a new method, `CreateRabbitMqMessageScheduler` that is an extension method on `IBus` that basically creates the required components to schedule using the delayed exchange:

```
 if (bus.Topology is IRabbitMqHostTopology topology)
     return new MessageScheduler(new DelayedExchangeScheduleMessageProvider(bus, topology));
```

That is what's done under the hood.

Comment: I'm stuck on version 5.2.1 of MassTransit, because of .net framework 4.5.2 ... I've tried by creating a `var delayedMessageScheduler = new DelayedExchangeMessageScheduler(_bus, topology, destinationUri);
` and sending the message from there. `delayedMessageSchedule.ScheduleSend( ... )` but this time the message doesn't even reach rabbit, and no exchange of type x-delayed-message created ... Still missing something!

Comment: but I can confirm that with MassTransit 6.2.4 on .net core 2.0 sending the message from `var ms = new MessageScheduler(new DelayedExchangeScheduleMessageProvider(bus, bus.Topology as IRabbitMqHostTopology))` like this `ms.ScheduleSend( ... )` works as expected. Thank you !!!